# JavaScript - Test if getAttributeNode, setAttributeNode and createAttribute are supported by browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, modernizr, jscript

How could I check if getAttributeNode, setAttributeNode and createAttribute functions are supported by browser?

I need  to detect by JavaScript the limit between IE6 and IE5.5 without Navigator User Agent(Using IEtester or IE console Emulator).

Why? Checking Modernizr browser support

Thanks!

---

Thanks Oriol! But being more specific, I need something like this:

```
var support = true;
if(typeof(document.getElementsByClassName) === 'undefined'){
    support = false;
    }

if(support){
    // IE > 8
    }else{
    // IE <= 8  
        }
```

But instead of IE 8, IE 5.5. 
Using getAttributeNode, setAttributeNode and createAttribute instead of document.getElementsByClassName

---

FOUND IT!!! using Oriol answer and video detection method from http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

```
function supports() {
    var Element = document.createElement('div'),
    Q1 = !!Element.getAttributeNode,
    Q2 = !!Element.setAttributeNode,
    Q3 = !!document.createAttribute;
    return Q1 && Q2 && Q3;
}

if(supports()){
    // IE > 5.5
    }else{
    // IE <= 5.5
        }
```

Comment: You can just use `if(myElement.getAttributeNode && myElement.setAttributeNode && myElement.createAttribute){do something}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to check if an object has some property:

```
'getAttributeNode' in myElement
&& 'setAttributeNode' in myElement
&& 'createAttribute' in document
```

`myElement` should be a reference to some element, e.g. `document.documentElement`.

The proper way would be checking in `Element.prototype` and `Document.prototype`, but old IE don't expose them. Therefore you should check in some instances, and assume it will work for the other ones too.

Note the code above only test the existence of the property. If you want to be safer you can also use `typeof` to check if they are functions.

Comment: And without DOM element? Like document.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: @lucasgabmoreno `getAttributeNode` and `setAttributeNode` are only available in `Element` instances, not in `Document` one.

Comment: function supports() {
    var Element = document.createElement('div'),
    Q1 = !!Element.getAttributeNode,
    Q2 = !!Element.setAttributeNode,
    Q3 = !!document.createAttribute;
    return Q1 && Q2 && Q3;
}

if(supports()){
    // IE > 5.5
    }else{
    // IE <= 5.5
        }